# Htaccess conflict rules

Tags: .htaccess

My Htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC,L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ departure.php?PDt2=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
      RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ service.php?DPt=$1&CTg=$2&NLs=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The rule of **service.php** url does not work.

Why the error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your rules around and adding conditions to both rules. See if this helps.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC,L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ service.php?DPt=$1&CTg=$2&NLs=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ departure.php?PDt2=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: the CSS did not work and the variables do not return. Rule service.php

Comment: CSS is easy to fix. You can use absolute paths for CSS or use `/` in front of the path. That is what happens with pretty URL's. But what do you mean variable do not return?